# Get data and put in this table

Tags: php, mysql, json, put

With this file We can get a CRUD table but I can't put data in this table because I am a beginner yet and low in this case. The data must be in jJSON data and I want to get the data from a mysql database through code PHP.

This is whole file: https://github.com/Askedio/jQuery-Cruddy/

Default file index:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

     <title>jQuery CRUDdy</title>

     <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
     <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="../src/css/jquery-cruddy.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
      /* For example page only. Not part of cruddy. */
      body{ margin: 40px 0 200px 0}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>


   <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>CRUD<sup>dy</sup></h1> 
      <p>A jQuery plugin to assist with JSON API driven CRUD tasks.</p> 
    </div>
   </div>


    <div class="container container-user">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">

        <div id="modal-create-edit" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
          <script id="create-edit" type="text/x-jsrender">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">
                      {{if id}}
                        Edit #{{:id}}
                      {{else}}
                        Create
                      {{/if}}
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="alert-control alert"></div>
                <p></p>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Full Name</label>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input name="name" class="form-control" value="{{:attributes.name}}">
                        <span class="help-block hide">
                            <strong></strong>
                        </span>                                
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input name="email" class="form-control" value="{{:attributes.email}}">
                        <span class="help-block hide">
                            <strong></strong>
                        </span>                                
                    </div>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <input name="id" class="hide" value="{{:id}}">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                  {{if id}}
                    Save
                  {{else}}
                    Create
                  {{/if}}
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </script>
          <form action="https://cruddy.io/app/api/admin/user" class="create-edit"></form>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="alert-control alert"></div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 hidden-xs">
            <h1 style="margin:0">User Management</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-refresh"><em class="fa fa-refresh"></em></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-create" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-create-edit">Create New</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <hr>

        <div class="panel panel-default panel-table">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col col-xs-7 col-md-9">
                <h3 class="panel-title">&nbsp;</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="col col-xs-5 col-md-3 text-right">

                <form class="form-inline search">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-list" data-href="test.php">
              <thead>
                <th><em class="fa fa-cog"></em></th>
                <th class="hidden-xs" data-col="id">ID <em class="fa fa-fw fa-sort pull-right em-sort"></th>
                <th data-col="name">Name <em class="fa fa-fw fa-sort pull-right em-sort"></em></th>
                  <th data-col="email">E-mail <em class="fa fa-fw fa-sort pull-   right em-sort"></em></th>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr><td colspan="4">Loading...</td></tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>

          </div>
          <div class="panel-footer">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col col-xs-4">
                <form class="form-inline">
                  <select name="limit" class="form-control">
                    <option>1
                    <option>10
                  </select>
                </form>
              </div>
              <div class="col col-xs-8 list-pagination">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

     </div>
    </div>
    </div>



    <script id="no-results" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5"><strong>No Results Found.</strong></td>
    </tr>
    </script>


    <script id="row-item" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-action="read" data-href="https://cruddy.io/app/api/admin/user/{{:id}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-create-edit"><em class="fa fa-pencil"></em></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-action="delete" data-href="https://cruddy.io/app/api/admin/user/{{:id}}"><em class="fa fa-trash">   </em></button>
     </td>
     <td class="hidden-xs">{{:id}}</td>
     <td>{{:attributes.name}}</td>
     <td>{{:attributes.email}}</td>
     </tr>
     </script>

      <script id="list-pagination" type="text/x-jsrender">
     <ul class="pagination pull-right">
      {{if links.prev}}<li><span data-href="{{:links.prev}}">&laquo;</span></li>  {{/if}}
      <li><span disabled>{{:meta.currentPage}} of {{:meta.total}}</span></li>
      {{if links.next}}<li><span data-href="{{:links.next}}">&raquo;</span></li>{{/if}}
      </ul>
      </script>


     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsrender/0.9.73/jsrender.min.js">      </script>
      <script   src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">        </script>
      <script src="../src/js/jquery-cruddy.js"></script>

     <script>
      $('.container-user').cruddy({'onLog': function($this, data)  {console.log(data)}});
      </script>
      </body>
     </html>
```

I am trying in this way but I am sure it is not right.

A simple testing (test.php) :

```
 $array = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Luciano', 'email' => 'lucianop@hotmail.com');

 echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Well, I cant put data inside this table, simply, I tried in this way but without success

Comment: That is not a question, and too broad anyway. Please ask a question, and make it specific: which part of the code do you have a problem with, what debugging have you done, and where are the variables different then expected. Don't expect us to read your whole application code.

Comment: in this code there are the table

Comment: in the tag table where there is the table that get the data there are data-href too, I believe where its all data from this table but in this whole file I download dont have this file, I just want a help because I am a begginer yet, but if I am a bugger here sorry, I gonna just get out and never ever repeat a question in this way again

Comment: You're not a bugger ;-) I just want to help you revise the question so you will get some interest in it. People are easily chased away when they see there are more than 100 lines of code to digest. Try to limit your code to the core of the issue, and make sure you ask a question (which you have still not done: you just state things, but never ask anything). If you want help, ask for what exactly(!) you need that help. Be concrete.

Comment: sorry, I cant do more than it, I said it already

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for using my package. I'm sorry that I haven't used it in some time.

The default setup uses the data provided by Laravel 5s pagination via my Laravel Cruddy package https://github.com/Askedio/laravel-Cruddy

You can provide the data yourself, It appears to be

```
['data' => [], 'meta' => []]
```

See what goes in data here:
https://github.com/Askedio/laravel-Cruddy/blob/master/src/Transformers/ApiTransformer.php#L157

I also pass the links to get the next set of data. The plugin uses the `listLaravel` method to paginate using the laravel package.

Comment: ok, this link is about 'meta' but what about of the 'data'? it would be 'data' [ 'id' => 'value', 'name' => 'value', 'email' => 'value', or not